# Implementing a trait for anything that implements a trait?

Tags: generics, rust, syntax, traits, implementation

I want to implement the trait [Add](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Add.html) trait for anything that implements `Into<u64>`.I tried this,

```rust
impl<T> Add<Into<T>> for Sequence {
    type Output = Self;
    fn add(self, rhs: T) -> Self::Output {
      todo!();
    }
}
```

This gives me two errors,

```
doesn't have a size known at compile-time
= help: the trait `Sized` is not implemented for `(dyn Into<T> + 'static)`
```

And,

```
`Into` cannot be made into an object
= note: the trait cannot be made into an object because it requires `Self: Sized`
= note: for a trait to be "object safe" it needs to allow building a vtable to allow the call to be resolvable dynamically; for more information visit <https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/traits.html#object-safety>
```

I've tried replacing that with,

```
impl<T> Add<dyn Into<T> + 'static + Sized> for Sequence {
```

But I'm still getting errors

```
doesn't have a size known at compile-time
= help: the trait `Sized` is not implemented for `(dyn Into<T> + 'static)`
note: required by a bound in `Add`
```

What's the right syntax here, I'm going down a rabbit hole?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax you want is,

```
impl<T: Into<u64>> Add<T> for Sequence {
  type Output = Self;
  fn add(self, rhs: T) -> Self::Output {
  ...
}
```

This will implement `Add<T>` for all `T` that implement `Into<u64>`

[I opened up a bug to get the compiler to provide more guidance](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/89140)